# Operating Systems supported by the Intel SR1435VP2 Server Platform?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel

I recently had two Intel SR1435VP2 Servers (with SE7320VP2 server boards) donated to me from a colleague. Google hasn't yielded much more than user manuals when searching for OS-compatibility answers.

I have worked with flavors of Linux such as Ubuntu and Debian, but Intel only documents that they have tested proprietary operating systems such as SuSE, Solaris and Red Hat as documented on their [driver downloads](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Server+Products&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+Server+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Server+Board+SE7320VP2) page.

Has anyone worked with these machines before, and if so, do you know if the SR1435VP2/E7320 chipset supports OS's such as CentOS, Debian or Ubuntu?

If you need more information or clarification, let me know. This is all new for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CentOS is a derivative of Red Hat's Linux, so if RH works then CentOS will too. With the age of the hardware and the popularity of it's chips I'd be shocked if all the major OSes (Linux, Windows, FreeBSD, Solaris) didn't support it (if not fully, at least functionally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very old server. The chipset used by that system is the Intel E7320, so the system is the first generation of 64-bit capable Intel systems on the market (EM64T). That will place the retail period of the systems at ~2004-2006.

The best way to get an accurate feel for the Linux drivers for a system like that is to run a Linux Rescue CD and take note of the modules loaded at boot.

But in general, I'd say that you're covered with any modern distribution. The only tricky issue may be the motherboard RAID controller, but you can always run software RAID. I'd say that you're well-covered with Linux and Windows. The chipset is already in the Linux kernel under the [e752x_edac driver](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/edac/e752x_edac.c?v=2.6.25).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply. That answered a lot of questions. I'm not really worried about RAID because I'm only utilizing a single HDD. I come from a unix background and windows was never a consideration. How would you say it is on the backend side of things?

Comment: @Xspence I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit my question for some reason. What I meant to say was..

The server does not have an optical drive installed. Is there another way that I could execute the test? What about a USB drive?

Comment: @Xspence No need to. I said that the chipset is supported by the `e752x_edac` driver. It's in the Linux kernel, so every post-2004 operating system will support this server.

Comment: Not to be redundant, but just to clarify.. Ubuntu 12.04 would be compatible, for example?

Comment: @Xspence yep...